# C Programming : Unions

Tags: c, unions

This program displays output as

> 0 3 1

```
main()
{
    union status {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
    };
    union status std1, std2, std3;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", std1, std2, std3);
    return 0;
}
```

Tested in Dev C++. Possibly

> 0 3 1

can't be garbage value. Please let me know.

Comment: it IS garbage! Try compiling it across different compilers

Comment: `std1` is not an int. Printing it with `%d` is undefined behavior[

Comment: Very valid point mentioned by @LưuVĩnhPhúc, please note.

Comment: Compile with set  `-Wall` option to _Compiler options_

Comment: I thought there would be something like enums...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An uninitialized variable has indeterminate value - it's just unknown what its value is. There's a valid memory address backing the variable and it has some garbage content.
and be aware that it is UB (undefined behavior) even if initialization is properly done. @BLUEPIXY

Comment: `%s/unspecified/indeterminate`.

Comment: `So in practice, with any sane implementation, this kind of code will presumably never crash`...well, it can , one of the side effects of UB. See my answer.

Comment: Please be aware that it is UB even if initialization is properly done.

Answer (score 4):

First, let me tell you while using as an argument to `%d`, you need to access a member (type `int`) of the union, you cannot pass the union itself. In it's current state, any conforming compiler will try to warn you with a message like

> format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘union status’ [-Wformat=]

Because, passing an incompatible type of argument causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

After that, regarding the value you see, it **is** indeterminate value. You cannot possibly have any specific output.

In your case, `std1`, `std2`, `std3` all are automatic local variable and unless initialized explicitly, they contain indeterminate values. Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. [...]

Think logically, you never *put* anything here, what do you expect to *retrieve*?

That said, this  causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as the type can have trap representation and the address was never taken, thus using the value invokes UB.

Comment: I wonder why you mention the actual reason (passing wrong type) more like a sub-issue. I'd concentrate on this and mention the missing initialiser as the second problem. **Both** invoke UB, btw. You defintively should emphasises this for the type missmatch issue!

Comment: I also agree with Olaf. This is the only correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are displaying unitialized data.  It is garbage by any definition - probably some leftovers after runtime linking.